# Even after limit is reached, condition is not getting true

Tags: bash

What is wrong with the following expression:

```
...
if [ $i -ge ${tLen} ]; then
     echo "Maximum limit reached, i=$i"
fi
i=$(($i+1))
...
```

This expression is inside a `while` loop.
`i` is the counter variable, whose initial value is 0. 
`tLen` stores the length of the array, whome I am traversing.
This condition is not getting `true` even when `i` reaches `tLen`. Where am I going wrong?

This is my complete code :

```
read filename
words=(5 2)
i=0
sed 's/ /\n/g' "$filename" >"tmp.txt"
while read word
do
  words[i]=$word
  i=$(($i+1))
  awk "/$word/ {count += 1} END{print count}" "tmp.txt" >>"tmp2.dat"
done <"tmp.txt"
i=0
tLen=${#words[@]}
echo "Length of words: ${tLen}"
declare -A wordMap
while read count
do
  if [ $i -ge ${tLen} ]; then
    echo "Maximum length reached, i=$i"
    break
  fi
  wordMap["${words[$i]}"]=$count
  i=$(($i+1))
done <"tmp2.dat"

rm "tmp.txt"
rm "tmp2.dat"
```

Actually I am trying to calculate the frequency of each word in a given text...

Comment: Please post the rest of your code. It's possible you've got a [subshell issue](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#grep_foo_bar_.7C_while_read_-r.3B_do_.28.28count.2B-.2B-.29.29.3B_done)

Comment: Works for me. Try running with `#!/bin/bash -xv` on the first line to see what's in your variables.

Comment: Im getting error `bad array subscript` what does it mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code would be problematic for texts that have empty lines in them, or multiple spaces between the words. In that case the line

```
wordMap["${words[$i]}"]=$count
```

would fail with a `bad array subscript` message because `${words[$i]}` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the "real" question, but if you just want to pragmatically count words in a file:

```
sed 's/[[:space:][:punct:]]/\n/g;' < testfil | sed '/^$/d' | sort -f | uniq -ci | sort -n
```

seems to work.

I can't obviously see the error in your code otherwise, especially not in the minimal example. Try inserting debug `echo` statements or setting `set -x` early in the code to get a minimal example that emulates the behaviour.